# localstack init.sh script run leads to "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh'" error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, localstack

I have a simple init.sh script (creating S3 buckets), which needs to be run in the localstack container after it's ready. Below is my docker compose file

```
localstack:
    image: ....../localstack/localstack:latest
    container_name: localstack
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=
      - AWS_REGION=us-east-1
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=fake
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=fake
      - HOSTNAME=localstack
      - HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL=localstack
    volumes:
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "${PWD}/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/init.sh:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh"
```

However, I got the error below:

```
Error while running script Script(path='/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh', stage=READY, state=ERROR)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/runtime/init.py", line 136, in run_stage
    runner.run(script.path)
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/runtime/init.py", line 69, in run
    exit_code = subprocess.call(args=[], executable=path)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 389, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1950, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh'
```

Clearly, it is a permission issue of the init-aws.sh, I checked it, it was `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 341 Dec  8 21:27 /etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh`. Thus, I tried to add

```
command: chmod +x /etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh && /docker-entrypoint.sh localstack
```

into my docker compose file to change the mode of the file. But it was not run at all cause I didn't see it printed out in the localstack log. Plus, the script still have permission issue and failed to run.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.